# Derivative at $0$ of $\int_0^x \sin \frac{1}{t} dt$

Tags: analysis

Let
$f(x)=\int_0^x \sin \frac{1}{t} dt   \textrm{ for }  x \in \mathbb R$.
Is $f$ differentiable at $0$ ?

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay That assumes that $f$ is continuously differentiable at 0; we don't even know that it is differentiable there.

Comment: It seems that I don't have much positive to say on this; I will tell you that Mathematica seems to believe that the derivative exists and is 0.  But this is not an easy problem to prove rigorously!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us consider the difference quotient

$$Q(x) := \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} = \frac1x \int_0^x \sin \frac1t\,dt$$

for small positive $x$ and apply a few substitutions:

$$\begin{align}
u = \frac1t &\leadsto Q(x) = \frac1x\int_{1/x}^\infty \frac{\sin u}{u^2}\,du\\
A = \frac1x &\leadsto Q(1/A)= A \int_A^\infty \frac{\sin u}{u^2}\,du\\
u = Ay &\leadsto Q(1/A) = A\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin (Ay)}{(Ay)^2}\, d(Ay) = \int_1^\infty \frac{\sin (Ay)}{y^2}\,dy.
\end{align}$$

Now, the [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_lemma) says<sup>(1)</sup>

$$\lim_{A\to\infty} Q(1/A) = 0,$$

in other words, $f$ is differentiable at $0$, with $f'(0)= 0$.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Riemann-Lebesgue is a bigger gun than is needed here, but it's an important thing to know, so its mention has a reason.

Here, we can do with partial integration:

$$\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin (Ay)}{y^2}\,dy &= \left[-\frac{\cos (Ay)}{Ay^2}\right]_1^\infty - \frac{2}{A}\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos (Ay)}{y^3}\, dy\\
&= \frac{1}{A} - \frac{2}{A} \int_1^\infty \frac{\cos (Ay)}{y^3}\, dy
\end{align}$$

and we can estimate

$$\left\lvert \int_1^\infty \frac{2\cos (Ay)}{y^3}\,dy\right\rvert \leqslant \int_1^\infty \frac{2}{y^3}\,dy = 1$$

to obtain

$$\lvert Q(1/A)\rvert \leqslant \frac{2}{A}.$$

Comment: I don't know if you saw my answer. Strong tool used here (+1) but don't we need the continuity of $\sin(1/t)$ here? Thanks

Comment: No, we don't need the continuity. The oscillation cancels so much of the integral that you have differentiability at $0$. In this simple case, we can also directly see the limit by partial integration. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for additional points. I am so eager to know this example for the next in my Class. Thanks.